# looking for Linux alternative to windows azure

Tags: php, azure, amazon-ec2, hosting, cloud

I am currently using Windows Azure to host a couple of websites.  At this point I have to say I love everything about it.  Its easy to start a site, and within just a few minutes you've FTP'd in and are writing code.  There is only one con from this whole picture and that is that these sites you set up are hosted on Windows IIS.

At this point my PHP is virtually non-existant, Im learning but so far all of my coding experience has been on servers with Apache running on Linux.  This is combined with the fact that I am developing on a Linux box.  I realize for more advanced users this IIS vs Apache stuff doesn't make a difference, but for me it is proving difficult.  At this point in my experience I would like to focus on learning PHP and not server nuances.

I have tried Amazon EC2, but I dont want to manage my site from a VPS command line.

My question is this; are there services like AppHarbor, or Heroku that offer quick simple scalable PHP hosting on Linux in a fashion similar to Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of choice like

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/ easy to use and scale.
```

this its another choice

```
https://www.appfog.com/
```

Comment: Good suggestion I ended up using appfog in the long run.